Issue parsing a string by iterating over the chars in Rust
I'm working on the 1brc challenge as a way to learn Rust. My approach involves reading the file in chunks and processing in parallel. To do this, I send the chunks over a channel as a Box<[u8]>. I convert this to a string and then iterate over the chars too construct a map of the cities and temperatures.
However, the block of code doing the parse keeps failing on the last k in Reykjavík on row 49. Works fine until then. Can someone point out the flaw in the logic?
Specifically, the error I see is that end_idx is off by one on the 49th row and ends up shifting left by one resulting in the city name "Reykjaví" and the next float parse failing.
const VALUE_SEPARATOR: char = ';';
const NEW_LINE: char = '\n'; 

//constants declared at the top   

for chunk in chunk_receiver {
        let chunk_string = std::str::from_utf8(&chunk).unwrap();

        let mut start_idx = 0;
        let mut end_idx = 0;
    
        for (idx, elem) in chunk_string.chars().enumerate() {
            match elem {
                VALUE_SEPARATOR => {
                    end_idx = idx;
                },
                NEW_LINE => {
                    let city = chunk_string[start_idx..end_idx].to_string();
                    start_idx = end_idx + 1;
                    

                    if (idx - end_idx) > 1 && city.len() > 0 {
                        let temperature: f32 = fast_float::parse::<f32, _>(chunk_string[start_idx..idx].as_bytes()).unwrap();
                        start_idx = idx + 1;

                        map.entry(city)
                            .and_modify(|metric| metric.update(temperature))
                            .or_insert_with(|| Metrics::new(temperature));
                    }
                },
                _ => {
                    continue;
                },
            };
        }
    }


Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Also, define "fail". Does it panic? Please provide the panic message. Does it print the wrong result? Please add the expected and actual outcome.

I just got back to this. I worked around by it avoid the string conversion and directly working with the u8 slice. Parsing that way fixed the issue.

Likely the problem wasn't with the "k" but with the "i" before it, you sliced at non-utf8 boundary.

Fixed the issue by parsing the u8 slice by itself without the string conversion.
